# image of the divergence operator

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. From Poincaré's inequality we know that the gradient is an isomorphism from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ onto $L^2(\Omega)^n$. Also, we know (from the Closed Map theorem) that the divergence operator is its dual operator from $L^2(\Omega)^n$ onto $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. My question is: do the constant functions belong to the image of the divergence?

Comment: Do you know an example of a smooth constant-divergence (in the classical coordinate-formula sense) vector field on $\mathbb R^n?$ It should be very easy to show the restriction to $\Omega$ is in $L^2,$ and to verify that it satisfies the definition via duality.

Comment: I meant the functions that are constant inside the domain and zero elsewhere, i.e. $1_{\Omega}$. I needed to see an explicit example of the uniqueness of the divergence operator.